# How to draw multiple images on canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, 2d

I am able to deal with one image, able to zoom and pan smoothly and also able to plot shapes on that image.

Drawing two images on canvas. But when I zoom it Chrome getting crash.

**gkhead.jpg is main image and on this image want to draw alphaball.png image.**

```
window.addEventListener('load', eventWindowLoaded, false);
    function eventWindowLoaded() {
       canvasApp();
    }
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    function canvasApp(){   
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        eventShipLoaded();
        function eventShipLoaded() {          
            draw1(scaleValue);
        }

        function draw1(scaleValue){                     
            var tileSheet = new Image();
            tileSheet.addEventListener('load', eventShipLoaded , false);
            tileSheet.src = "gkhead.jpg";   

            var tileSheet1 = new Image();
            tileSheet1.addEventListener('load', eventShipLoaded , false);
            tileSheet1.src = "alphaball.png";           

            var x = 0; 
            var y =  0;     
            var width = 480;
            var height = 480;

            context.save();     
            context.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)   
            context.globalAlpha = 0.5;          
            //context.drawImage(tileSheet,x,y, width, height);
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);   
            context.restore();
            //drawBoard();
            context.save(); 
            context.drawImage(tileSheet, x, y, tileSheet.width*scaleValue, tileSheet.height*scaleValue);            
            context.scale(scaleValue, scaleValue);
            context.drawImage(tileSheet1, 200, 200, 40/scaleValue, 40/scaleValue);
            context.restore();

            /*context.globalAlpha = 0.5;            
            context.fillStyle = "blue";
            context.fillRect(180, 180, 40 / scaleValue, 40 / scaleValue);   
            context.fillRect(260, 190, 40 / scaleValue, 40 / scaleValue);*/ 

        }; 


            var scaleValue = 1;
            var scaleMultiplier = 0.8;
            var startDragOffset = {};
            var mouseDown = false;          
            // add button event listeners
            document.getElementById("plus").addEventListener("click", function(){           
                scaleValue /= scaleMultiplier;              
                draw1(scaleValue);
                //eventShipLoaded();
            }, false);
             document.getElementById("minus").addEventListener("click", function(){
                scaleValue *= scaleMultiplier;
                //draw1(scaleValue);                
                eventShipLoaded();
            }, false);
            document.getElementById("original_size").addEventListener("click", function(){
                scaleValue = 1;
                //draw1(scaleValue);        
                eventShipLoaded();
            }, false);

        var isDown = false;
        var startCoords = [];
        var last = [0, 0];

        canvas.onmousedown = function(e){
            isDown = true;

            startCoords = [
                e.offsetX - last[0],
                e.offsetY - last[1]
           ];
        };

        canvas.onmouseup   = function(e){
            isDown = false;

            last = [
                e.offsetX - startCoords[0], // set last coordinates
                e.offsetY - startCoords[1]
            ];
        };

        canvas.onmousemove = function(e){
            if(!isDown) return;

            var x = e.offsetX;
            var y = e.offsetY;
            context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, x - startCoords[0], y - startCoords[1]);
            //draw1(scaleValue);    
            eventShipLoaded();
        }   

    }
```

Comment: Please put your code or snippet.

Comment: @NK : updated question with my code. Kindly take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the possibility of recursion here. You are attached load event to image before you draw it. And you are attached draw1() itself when you are in it. When you start draw image on canvas draw1() get triggered and start drawing image again and this will continue recursively...